# Cascading Dropdown using javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have this code in javascript but it is not working. can someone check my code?
By the way i just got this code from one of the question here. thanks

```
function CollegeDepartment() {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("college");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("department");
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "College of Engineering") {
        var optionArray = ["Civil Engineering", "Computer Engineering", "Electrical Engineering", "Electronics and Communication Engineering, Industrial Engineering, Mechanical Engineering"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CAS") {
        var optionArray = ["Political Science", "Mascomm", "Liacomm"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Commerce") {
        var optionArray = ["Business Ad", "Hotel Management", "Tourism"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Education") {
        var optionArray = ["SPED"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CICCT") {
        var optionArray = ["Computer Science", "Information Technology"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = optionArray[option];
        newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control" name="college" id="college" runat="server" oninput="CollegeDepartment()">
                 <option selected>Select College</option>
                 <option value="College of Engineering">College of Engineering</option>
                 <option value="CAS">College of Arts and Science</option>
                 <option value="Commerce">College of Commerce</option>
                 <option value="Education">College of Education</option>
                 <option value="CICCT">CICCT</option>   
             </select>
        </div>
            <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Department" >
                <option value="Department" selected>Select Department</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: Create a snippet to show us what is not working, cost some of my time to create one **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vkeaL1r/)**, however, it just works fine.

Comment: @fuyushimoya it will work in fiddle but i don't know why it will not work on the visual studio?

Comment: @fuyushimoya I'm using aspx by the way. do you have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: Somehow aspx is not something I'm familiar with, did you add something like onchange,oninput as I added in jsfiddle? Can't give more advice other than this.

Comment: @fuyushimoya it's ok thank you and i added oninput

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML please?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz already edited my question and added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your problem right away, you was using the `oninput` event what you needed was `onchange`

So this:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="college" id="college" runat="server" oninput="CollegeDepartment()">
```

Becomes:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="college" id="college" runat="server" onchange="CollegeDepartment()">
```

```js
function CollegeDepartment() {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("college");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("department");
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "College of Engineering") {
        var optionArray = ["Civil Engineering", "Computer Engineering", "Electrical Engineering", "Electronics and Communication Engineering, Industrial Engineering, Mechanical Engineering"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CAS") {
        var optionArray = ["Political Science", "Mascomm", "Liacomm"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Commerce") {
        var optionArray = ["Business Ad", "Hotel Management", "Tourism"];
    } else if (s1.value == "Education") {
        var optionArray = ["SPED"];
    } else if (s1.value == "CICCT") {
        var optionArray = ["Computer Science", "Information Technology"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = optionArray[option];
        newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
};
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="college" id="college" runat="server" onchange="CollegeDepartment()">
                 <option selected>Select College</option>
                 <option value="College of Engineering">College of Engineering</option>
                 <option value="CAS">College of Arts and Science</option>
                 <option value="Commerce">College of Commerce</option>
                 <option value="Education">College of Education</option>
                 <option value="CICCT">CICCT</option>   
             </select>
        </div>
            <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Department" >
                <option value="Department" selected>Select Department</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Try the above snippent, alternatively here is a CodePen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPpWJp

Comment: You're very welcome Rigel, it's a simple mistake, I've certainly made it before.